# Why Can't I reset the 'last cell'

Tags: excel, vba, openxml

I'm trying to reset the last cell of my sheet.

The last cell that has data is DD1004 but it shows EZ 1048000 in the end.

I have already tried everything, macros, clear, delete the line, delete the column, macros again of other 10 posts and none seem to reset.

So I decided to take a look into the XML of the sheet.

As you can see in the image, there is nothing in the sheet. do you guys know what is impeding me to reset the last cell?

[image]

Comment: "The last cell that has data is DD1004..."   "...there is nothing in the sheet..." -- so which one is it? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: How are you determining the last cell?

Comment: Select all rows between 1004 and 1048000. Click Delete rows. Save the file.

Comment: Already tried deleting and saving.

Comment: Sorry, there is nothing in the sheet after the cell DD1004

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue in the past, though I was trying to find and select the last cell.  It would give me a cell reference way off of the actual last cell. I found this website very helpful:
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba
In the link, it references refreshing the used range.  Maybe try that code.  You seem competent in macros but if you need help with the code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my problem.

The issue was that the last rows were using a custom height. Once I managed to apply the standard height to them, the usedrange was recalculated and changed to roll 1022.